# Компиляция проекта Python в exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

У меня есть проект с несколькими папками и файлами:

[image: Структура проекта]

И при сборке через **pyinstaller** у меня вылезает ошибка, что не хватает папок. Как можно их добавить в .exe файл при компиляции?
Если что, я в первый раз пытаюсь скомпилировать проект

Comment: вообще, про это много где написано - вот первая ссылка в яндексе - https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

если при компиляции в pyinstaller добавил флаг --onefile то файлы и папки подключенные к файлу нужно поместить в одну папку с файлом exe (возможно это не сработает)